# Parse m3u8 regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have m3u8 file from what i need to grab duration of ts file so that i can calculate bitrate of video i im using this samle and regex that i try to accomplish:

```
https://regex101.com/r/1oC5R1/1
```

I im getting:

```
#EXTINF:11.760000
#EXTINF:10.000000
#EXTINF:10.000000
#EXTINF:1.400000
```

And would like to get this:

```
11.760000
10.000000
10.000000
1.400000
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just use a capturing group: `#EXTINF:(\d+\.\d+)`

Comment: So... a capturing group? https://regex101.com/r/1oC5R1/2

Comment: Thanks! Now is working...i im learning regex and this is what i don't know before...works like charm...thanks again.

Comment: Just need to ask how can i get in javascript seconds result...online regex tester shows Group 1 and i don't know how to read group 1 i im only getting Full match

Comment: Javascript regex examples and explanations are abundant on the Internet. Hundreds of thousands of examples, blog posts, explanations, walkthroughs, documentation, you name it. Everything is there if you invest a minimum of effort into finding out. Your problem is not even difficult. Don't be so lazy.

Comment: ok..thanks you are right..i will find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a group with `()`, i.e.:

```
#EXTINF:(\d+\.\d+)
```

---

https://regex101.com/r/1oC5R1/3